# Is $|x-y| \le 7$ symetric relation?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

to prove $(x-y)$ divisible by $3$ as symmetric we use this method:
let $xRy$ belongs to $A$
$$
\begin{align}
 (x-y)&=3k \\
 -(x-y)&=-3k \\
 (y-x)&=3(-k)
\end{align}
$$
therefore $yRx$ also belongs to $A$.

Now how do I prove $|x-y|\le 7$ as symmetric? I'm not able to understand.
Or is it symmetric because of mod function and we don't use this method?

Comment: Just do the *appropriate* same steps.  $|a-b| =\begin{cases} a-b&a\ge b\\b-a&a<b\end{cases};|b-a| =\begin{cases}a-b&a\ge b\\b-a&a<b\end{cases}$ so $|a-b|\le 7\iff \begin{cases}a-b\le 7&a\ge b\\ b-a \le 7&a< b\end{cases}$. While $|b-a|\le 7\iff \begin{cases}a-b\le 7&a\ge b\\ b-a \le 7&a< b\end{cases}$ so $|a-b|\le 7 \iff |b-a|\le 7$.  So symmetric.... shoot that fly with that bazooka!

Answer (score 2):

Let $S = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid |x-y| \le 7 \}$.

Since $|x-y| = |y-x|$, if $(x,y) \in S$ then $(y,x) \in S$. Hence, symmetric.

Comment: thanks for the ans

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is symmetric.  I think the most fruitful way to look at it would be to do the definitions literally.

If $|a-b| \le 7$ does that mean $|b-a| \le 7$.

And then answer is: as $|a-b| = |b-a|$ then whatever is true about $|a-b|$ is true about  $|b-a|$ as they are the same thing.  So yes. If $|a-b| \le 7$ then $|b-a| =|a-b| \le 7$.

....

If you really want to plod through but pound it close with a sledgehammer.

Case 1)  $a \ge b$ and if $k = a-b$ then $k \ge 0$.  So $|a-b| =|k| = k$.  If $k \le 7$ then $|b-a| = |-k| = k$ and $k \le 7$ so that is symmetric if $a \ge b$.

Case 2)  $a < b$ and if $j = b-a > 0$ then $|a-b| = |-j| = j$. If $j \le 7$ then $|b-a| =|j| = j \le 7$ so that is symmetric of $b < a$.

So for all $a,b$..... if $|a-b| \le 7$ then $|b-a| = |a-b| \le 7$.

=====

The less fruitful way would be:

if an operation $*$ is commutative then the relation $a*b$ has property $X$ will always be symmetric.  This is because $a*b = b*a$ so whatever property $a*b$ has then $b*a$ will have it as it is the same thing.

And the operation $a*b := |a-b|$ is commutative.

Comment: thanks for the ans